# embedding images,javascriptfiles in custom server control asp.net

Tags: image, embedding

I want to make an html editor like ajax editor. I mean to say everything is merged in a single dll(images,javascript,class).

How to accomplish this.

Plz Help

Answer (score 2):

This [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910442) is really a good reference for how to do this and if you read this article closely, you'll also see a way to "perform substitution" within text-based embedded resources like CSS and JavaScript files as well.  The WebResource attribute has a PerformSubstitution property that, if set to true, will allow you to use WebResource URLs inside of your embedded resources.  This gives you the ability to reference embedded images within CSS selectors in the embedded CSS file.

In the AssemblyInfo file, you'd specify PerformSubstitution like this:

```
[assembly: WebResource("SimpleControl.MyScript.js", "text/javascript", PerformSubstitution = true)]
```

Inside the JavaScript file, you can use this bit of code to access a specific resource by name as it is in the assembly (namespace and all):

```
<%= WebResource("SimpleControl.smallSuccess.gif")%>
```

In general ASP.NET server controls that do default skinning (take Telerik's controls as an example) have everything embedded in the assembly.  I have written several controls that use this technique in the past and in current projects and it works very well.  If your CSS is written properly, you can even allow good overriding of the styling external to the controls to allow further customization to the provided defaults and/or skins.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WebResourceAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webresourceattribute.aspx). [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910442) might be helpful as well.

Comment: that's fine. I know some basics to include javascript and css. Main problem is images. Images are embedded but not displayed.

Comment: Images are static resources just as css and javascript, so if you successfully embed css and javascript and are capable of referencing them in a web page, there's no reason why images won't work. Do you get some errors or the links are broken?

Comment: Thanks,
But
If i do something like this

Image _img = new Image();
            _img.ImageUrl = this.Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(MyCustomControl), "image1.jpg");
            this.Controls.Add(_img);
 then images are displayed. For this i will have to make many instances of Image Control. Is this a must. There are many images. How to do that.